# Button onClick is not working inside a react functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

I have just started learning Reactjs and stuck on this very basic button issue. I have a functional component named `Todo` which has a button delete inside it. It has `onClick` attribute and it runs a function `deleteHandler`, but when I click the button nothing happens. `App.js` and `Todo.js` codes are given below:

App.js code

```js
import Todo from "./components/Todo.js";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Todos</h1>
      <Todo title="1st todo" />
      <Todo title="2nd todo" />
      <Todo title="3rd todo" />
      <Todo title="4th todo" />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Todo.js code

```
function Todo(props) {
    
      function deleteHandler() {
        console.log("U just deleted!");
      }
    
      return (
        <div className="card">
          <div className="content-card">
            <div>
              <h2>{props.title}</h2>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button type="button" className="btn" onClick={deleteHandler}>
                Delete
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }

export default Todo;
```

Comment: I've just tested this and your code works. Are you getting any errors? Have you exported/imported your components correctly?

Comment: As Andy pointed out, your code is correct and does run. Your question doesn't have any errors that can help us pinpoint the issue you're having either. Can you clarify what you want/what the issue is/

Comment: @Andy, I'm not getting any errors. And yes, imports and exports are correct. The whole website is working fine. Though, the button seems dead.

Comment: @PiratePie, I want this button to show the message that is logged by the function onClick. But when I open the console, there neither I get any error nor the message is appeared. The console appears empty.

Comment: @Farah I've run your code in Chrome, Edge and Firefox and it seems to work just fine for me, are you sure you've pasted in the correct code? Here's a link to a CodeSandbox with your code where you can see it actually runs. https://codesandbox.io/s/todo-stackoverflow-fzprs1

Comment: @PiratePie I pasted the correct code. And also, this happens with me a lot that I do some changes and the browser doesn't show any change at all. And when I close the chrome and visual studio code, everything then with the same code starts to work fine after restarting. I don't know what really happens behind the scenes.

Comment: Seems to be something on your end then, make sure to run `npm start` and save your files after changing them. This should trigger a rebuild which should update your dev environment

Answer (score 0):

Restarting IDE and the browser seems to solve this problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).